# Cannot connect via RDP between 2 Windows VMs

Tags: windows, server, virtualbox, rdp

I've got 2 VMs hosted on VirtualBox:

VM - Windows Server 2012 R2

- Ethernet: 10.0.2.15 (NAT with the host laptop)
- Ethernet 2: 192.168.0.1 (internal network)
- Port 3389: listening

VM - Windows 10 Enterprise

- Ethernet: 10.0.2.15 (NAT with the host laptop)
- Ethernet 2: 192.168.0.2 (internal network)

Host laptop - Windows 7 Enterprise

- Port forwarding set up in VirtualBox: local port 9090 <=> remote port
  3389

---

- Connection laptop -> Windows Server: works well
- Connection VM Windows 10 -> Windows Server: no connection, error:

[image]

Troubleshooting:

1. The port 3389 is open and listening on the server.
2. Both VMs can ping themselves.
3. Firewall on the client VM Windows 10 is turned off.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: despite both interfaces belonging to an internal network, I had to allow RDP work on a public network:

[image]